# Download shared S3 object using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-s3

I have created the S3 bucket in my AWS account and make the objects publically accessible from the console using the "Make Public" option.
I am able to download the objects using "wget" or browser from anywhere. This takes a very long time to download the 60gb object while it takes less time when downloaded through AWS CLI.

How can I download the same objects using AWS CLI from other AWS accounts?

I came across the IAM role to grant S3 permissions to another account. Is there any simplest way?
The S3 objects are not confidential and can be shared publicly.

Comment: If it's public, you don't need any permissions , you need to make sure that the IAM user/role you're using has S3 permission at IAM policy , nothing requires at S3.

Comment: Who is doing the downloading? Is it you, or an external person? I'm asking this because it determines whether to give them AWS credentials. Also, what time difference are you talking about when comparing a wget vs AWS CLI download? Are the timing comparisons being done on the same computer?

Comment: Hi John, Sorry for the late replay.
The external person will download the S3 object.
Below is the time taken to download 9.5G object.
time wget https://abc.s3.amazonaws.com/xyz/file.tar.gz  10,101,178,255 38.0MB/s   in 3m 42s
real    3m42.116s
user    0m10.185s
sys     0m32.778s

time aws s3 cp s3://abc/xyz/file.tar.gz . (120.1 MiB/s)
real    1m22.844s
user    1m2.068s
sys     0m59.381s